# How to make this serializer (python django) to convert comments under a post to Json data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
from .models import User, Post, Project, Comment, Version, Tag
from rest_framework import serializers
import bcrypt
from .models import Stock

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta: 
        model = posts
        fields = 'all'

def create(self, validated_data):
```

I cant figure out how to make it convert the data

Comment: Could you please provide more detail of what you are trying to achieve, and perhaps share the models' code if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to Django and I am not completely sure about the approach that I have mentioned below.

*Not tested*

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = 'Post'
        fields = 'all'

class PostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comment = CommentSerializer()
    title = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
```